# Como tornar um link apresentável

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, aplicação-web

Como faço pra "indexar" um link em um site para exibir ele de forma mais apresentável? 
Exemplo de sites/app que fazem isso é o whatsapp, facebook, gmail.
Por exemplo, no whatsapp é só colar um link e esperar alguns segundos que ele pega uma imagem e título do link e deixa-o mais apresentável.
Se tiver algum plugin em php, ou javascript, ou jquery, etc, que faça isso já ajuda muito. Pretendo aplicar essa solução na linguagem Php.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Não sei se "indexar" é o termo correto, mas se alguém souber, mesmo que inglês, pode passar o termo correto para eu pesquisar.

Comment: Observe no código fonte as tags `meta name="og:image"` e `meta property="og:title"`. As tags contém esse tipo de informação.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O responsável por gerar essas informações é o próprio produtor do conteúdo. Então, para fazer isso você precisa 'abrir' a página a ponto de ler o código-fonte dela para obter esses parâmetros meta:

**Mas é você quem tem que montar um HTML formatado do seu jeito para exibir onde você vai querer.**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Basicamente, veja as tags og:title, og:description, og:image e og:url.

O facebook tem uma ferramente que permite você fazer testes com qualquer url.
Acesse: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/

Cole algum link lá e veja o link 'indexado' além dessas meta tags lidas.
Veja um exemplo com esse link http://gifs.splitz.com.br/?p=6921 (que a propósito sou eu mesmo no GIF rsrsrs):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

O nome disso é The Open Graph protocol ([http://ogp.me/](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KzGQI.png))
Localiza no Google por "plugin The Open Graph protocol" e veja o que é aplicável ao que você precisa.

**Ache alguma coisa aqui: https://goo.gl/Lhclr6**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]